# Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined when trying to put data in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting this error: "Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined" when trying to insert data into a database. The error shows on:

**db.coordinates.*insert*({ "x" : "data.x", "y" : "data.y"})**

Database name - "node5"
Collection name - "coordinates"

```
// Including libraries
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var static = require('node-static'); // for serving files

//db connection

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/node5');



var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/node5';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server.");
  db.close();
});

// This will make all the files in the current folder
// accessible from the web
var fileServer = new static.Server('./');

// This is the port for our web server.
// you will need to go to http://localhost:8080 to see it
app.listen(8080);

// If the URL of the socket server is opened in a browser
function handler(request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        fileServer.serve(request, response);
    }).resume();
}

// Delete this row if you want to see debug messages
io.set('log level', 1);


// Listen for incoming connections from clients
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // Listen for mouse move events
    socket.on('post', function (data) {
        console.log('posted');
        console.log(data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('posted', data); // Broadcasts event to everyone except originating client
        db.coordinates.insert({ "x" : "data.x", "y" : "data.y"})
    });
});
```

When writing an answer, please note that I'm new to node.js and I might not understand if you tell the answer in a complex way:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `monk` for your project, then you can drop the `mongodb` module, since it's functionality is being wrapped up by monk. From [Monk's documentation](https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/GETTING_STARTED.html), you should be doing something like:

```
const monk = require('monk');
const db = monk('localhost:27017/node5')

const coordinates = db.get('coordinates');
```

Now that you have a reference to your **coordinates** collection, you can use it later in your code:

```
coordinates.insert({ x: data.x, y: data.y });
```

I hope this is easy enough to understand. If it is still confusing, then please comment below and I'll elaborate further :)

Comment: Thank you very much. That was very well explained and worked perfectly.

Could I ask one more quick question? How do I take data.x and data.y from the database? What function do I need to use? Thanks again.

Comment: You will need to use [Find](https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/collection/find.html) with the search criteria you need to filter the results.

Comment: Allright. I don't want to create new topic, so I will ask one more question.

I want to get 10 latest entries from database (data.x and data.y). I've found that I can use db.collection.find().skip(db.collection.count() - 10) to do that. But is it possible to convert that into array? Because I need all these entries separated, so I can use every data.x and data.y ?

Comment: You can convert a cursor to an array using `.toArray()` method to get an array. It would be something like `db.collection.find().skip(db.collection.count() - 10).toArray(/* callbacks */)`

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much. When I add coordinates.find().skip(coordinates.count() - 10).toArray(/* callbacks */) on the connection socket, it shows me TypeError: coordinates.find(...).skip is not a function error. I think its because of mangoose, it doesn't allow me this conversation. What else can I do?

Comment: If mongoose/monk don't expose the `Skip()` function then you will have to look for another ODM for MongoDB or use the native driver. There are a [lot of other modules](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/mongodb) so you will have to do some research on what suits you best.

Comment: Last question I hope so, `collection.find().skip(collection.count() - 10).toArray()` it says callback is mandatory. I don't really understand them yet, maybe you could help me with this?

Comment: You should read up on [Async Programming in JavaScript](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2012/12/09/callbacks-listeners-promises/) since you will be using it a lot. There is [lots of information](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) available on them. Some [advanced topics](http://callbackhell.com/), and [some for beginners](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/javascript-callbacks-explained-using-minions-da272f4d9bcd#.jbgw50xso). Reading this will give you the best understanding.